# I want to change my git id from cli on which i am currently working, so how i could i change this?

Tags: github, command-line-interface

I want to change my git id from cli on which I am currently working, so how could I change this?

I tried to change it by using the following commands :

1. `git config --global user.name "Your New Name"`
2. `git config --global user. email "yournew@email.com"`

but it did not work, Any suggestions?